# SVG with odd definitions and CSS Animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

Recently I began experimenting with CSS Animations over an SVG definition created by someone else and I found something I could n't solve by myself. And given my little about SVG, it was hard to Google a solution.

Here's what I've got:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box {
    max-height: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
}

svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

svg path {
    fill: #0f68e0;
}

.left {
    transform-origin: 190px 555px;
    /*animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;*/
}

.right {
    transform-origin: 605px 555px;
    /*animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;*/
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<wrapper class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

  <main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="logo">

          <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 796.209 765.469" enable-background="new 0 0 796.209 765.469" xml:space="preserve">

            <g>

              <circle id="left" cx="190" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="left">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,485.11c1.139-5.168,2.036-10.402,3.458-15.492
                                                                 c6.393-22.867,20.793-39.549,40.947-51.354c34.3-20.092,68.711-39.997,103.208-59.748c31.154-17.838,62.052-16.47,92.784,1.582
                                                                 c32.845,19.292,65.925,38.18,98.85,57.336c30.349,17.658,45.821,44.029,45.862,79.242c0.045,39.324,0.059,78.648-0.007,117.973
                                                                 c-0.058,34.592-15.114,60.828-44.834,78.314c-34.405,20.244-68.957,40.246-103.655,59.984c-28.94,16.463-58.437,16.797-87.462,0.377
                                                                 c-35.178-19.898-70.117-40.229-104.953-60.723c-24.501-14.416-39.667-35.475-43.343-64.141c-0.102-0.797-0.561-1.547-0.854-2.318
                                                                 C0,579.131,0,532.122,0,485.11z M70.932,555.338c0,22.164,0.074,44.326-0.081,66.488c-0.023,3.285,1.021,4.994,3.865,6.617
                                                                 c38.42,21.941,76.777,43.994,115.087,66.127c2.745,1.584,4.771,1.902,7.687,0.215c38.438-22.244,76.941-44.373,115.497-66.414
                                                                 c2.797-1.598,3.944-3.25,3.935-6.578c-0.124-44.158-0.115-88.316-0.016-132.475c0.007-3.215-0.884-5.018-3.791-6.678
                                                                 c-38.713-22.1-77.351-44.33-115.946-66.633c-2.487-1.436-4.269-1.418-6.729,0.002c-38.602,22.289-77.237,44.523-115.957,66.609
                                                                 c-2.979,1.699-3.626,3.627-3.611,6.732C70.982,511.346,70.931,533.342,70.932,555.338z"/>

              </g>

              <circle id="right" cx="605" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="right">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M796.181,555.313c0,19.5-0.115,39.002,0.025,58.502
                                                                 c0.257,35.969-15.705,62.445-46.587,80.311c-32.976,19.076-66.024,38.029-98.902,57.271c-31.076,18.188-62.064,18.539-93.234,0.455
                                                                 c-34.249-19.869-68.659-39.469-102.706-59.682c-28.814-17.105-43.453-42.863-43.624-76.43c-0.204-40-0.16-80.002-0.018-120
                                                                 c0.12-33.539,14.444-59.504,43.257-76.639c35.46-21.092,71.12-41.875,107.151-61.972c30.308-16.905,60.521-14.384,90.129,3.015
                                                                 c32.843,19.302,65.971,38.121,98.863,57.341c30.086,17.58,45.712,43.691,45.651,78.824
                                                                 C796.153,515.977,796.181,535.645,796.181,555.313z M728.073,555.583c0-21.832-0.099-43.664,0.093-65.496
                                                                 c0.034-3.813-1.063-5.908-4.44-7.838c-38.433-21.934-76.784-44.014-115.077-66.191c-2.938-1.701-5.012-1.23-7.662,0.297
                                                                 c-38.331,22.109-76.691,44.166-115.103,66.137c-2.759,1.58-3.927,3.246-3.917,6.592c0.133,44.33,0.119,88.662,0.021,132.992
                                                                 c-0.006,3.07,0.991,4.709,3.654,6.23c38.277,21.873,76.521,43.805,114.649,65.934c3.568,2.072,6.048,1.928,9.46-0.047
                                                                 c38.011-22.002,76.078-43.906,114.229-65.664c3.254-1.855,4.196-3.883,4.171-7.447C727.994,599.249,728.073,577.417,728.073,555.583
                                                                 z"/>

              </g>

            </g>

          </svg>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </main>

</wrapper>
```

It's static, I know, I've commented out the animation part which, in this early stage, is simply to make the `<path>` spin counter-clockwise.

But if you uncomment the animation lines you'll notice that, at some angles of the rotation, the vertices disappear, like if the whole SVG is behind something with some sort of background (like the tricks we usually do with overflow).

From the little I could dig up, I came to think that the problem is with the `<svg>` definition. In all examples I've seen, none of them was like that. I tried removing the `width` and `height` attributes as several tutorials suggested and even increasing the `viewBox` or add some padding (that was really a blind-shot) but nothing changed.

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the `viewBox` solves the issue on my side:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box {
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #0f68e0;
}

.left {
  transform-origin: 190px 555px;
  animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.right {
  transform-origin: 605px 555px;
  animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<wrapper class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

  <main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="logo">

          <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-20 0 841.209 765.469" enable-background="new -20 0 840.209 765.469" xml:space="preserve">

            <g>

              <circle id="left" cx="190" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="left">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,485.11c1.139-5.168,2.036-10.402,3.458-15.492
                                                                 c6.393-22.867,20.793-39.549,40.947-51.354c34.3-20.092,68.711-39.997,103.208-59.748c31.154-17.838,62.052-16.47,92.784,1.582
                                                                 c32.845,19.292,65.925,38.18,98.85,57.336c30.349,17.658,45.821,44.029,45.862,79.242c0.045,39.324,0.059,78.648-0.007,117.973
                                                                 c-0.058,34.592-15.114,60.828-44.834,78.314c-34.405,20.244-68.957,40.246-103.655,59.984c-28.94,16.463-58.437,16.797-87.462,0.377
                                                                 c-35.178-19.898-70.117-40.229-104.953-60.723c-24.501-14.416-39.667-35.475-43.343-64.141c-0.102-0.797-0.561-1.547-0.854-2.318
                                                                 C0,579.131,0,532.122,0,485.11z M70.932,555.338c0,22.164,0.074,44.326-0.081,66.488c-0.023,3.285,1.021,4.994,3.865,6.617
                                                                 c38.42,21.941,76.777,43.994,115.087,66.127c2.745,1.584,4.771,1.902,7.687,0.215c38.438-22.244,76.941-44.373,115.497-66.414
                                                                 c2.797-1.598,3.944-3.25,3.935-6.578c-0.124-44.158-0.115-88.316-0.016-132.475c0.007-3.215-0.884-5.018-3.791-6.678
                                                                 c-38.713-22.1-77.351-44.33-115.946-66.633c-2.487-1.436-4.269-1.418-6.729,0.002c-38.602,22.289-77.237,44.523-115.957,66.609
                                                                 c-2.979,1.699-3.626,3.627-3.611,6.732C70.982,511.346,70.931,533.342,70.932,555.338z"/>

              </g>

              <circle id="right" cx="605" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="right">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M796.181,555.313c0,19.5-0.115,39.002,0.025,58.502
                                                                 c0.257,35.969-15.705,62.445-46.587,80.311c-32.976,19.076-66.024,38.029-98.902,57.271c-31.076,18.188-62.064,18.539-93.234,0.455
                                                                 c-34.249-19.869-68.659-39.469-102.706-59.682c-28.814-17.105-43.453-42.863-43.624-76.43c-0.204-40-0.16-80.002-0.018-120
                                                                 c0.12-33.539,14.444-59.504,43.257-76.639c35.46-21.092,71.12-41.875,107.151-61.972c30.308-16.905,60.521-14.384,90.129,3.015
                                                                 c32.843,19.302,65.971,38.121,98.863,57.341c30.086,17.58,45.712,43.691,45.651,78.824
                                                                 C796.153,515.977,796.181,535.645,796.181,555.313z M728.073,555.583c0-21.832-0.099-43.664,0.093-65.496
                                                                 c0.034-3.813-1.063-5.908-4.44-7.838c-38.433-21.934-76.784-44.014-115.077-66.191c-2.938-1.701-5.012-1.23-7.662,0.297
                                                                 c-38.331,22.109-76.691,44.166-115.103,66.137c-2.759,1.58-3.927,3.246-3.917,6.592c0.133,44.33,0.119,88.662,0.021,132.992
                                                                 c-0.006,3.07,0.991,4.709,3.654,6.23c38.277,21.873,76.521,43.805,114.649,65.934c3.568,2.072,6.048,1.928,9.46-0.047
                                                                 c38.011-22.002,76.078-43.906,114.229-65.664c3.254-1.855,4.196-3.883,4.171-7.447C727.994,599.249,728.073,577.417,728.073,555.583
                                                                 z"/>

              </g>

            </g>

          </svg>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </main>

</wrapper>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but although it solves for the right spinning, it doesn't work for the left side, and both paths will be spinning at the same time. Worse! If I keep increasing, not only it doesn't solve as I would expect, but the whole SVG shrinks. And, let's consider a scenario in which I would add more definitions, by my own, at different coordinates (top, for example), doing the same as you did for the viewBox height (i.e. increasing the 765.469) does nothing either.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto I also fixed the right side ;) didn't notice it ... By the way, the main issue is that you are relying on a ready SVG that you try to adjust to your needs which is not always easy. But the general fix, is to always increase the viewBox to create the needed space for rotation, or make 2 SVG and rotate the SVG instead of the paths

Comment: I would have never guessed I had to use negative values on the first two arguments for that. Well, just before I mark as solved, is there any sort of ratio between these values? Because my intention, for later, is to add some spacing so the vertices don't touch each other while spinning. With this in mind, I defined a *viewBox* of `1024x1024` and, by trial and error, I had to use `125` for both axes to have the whole image centered in the *viewBox*.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto no there is no specific relation between those values .. the viewBow allow you define the rectangle of the view, So you simply increase/decrease what you see inside the SVG, then your ratio is defined by the values you specify there