# Animate SVG fill back-and-forth

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

After an [odd issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51152936/753531) I had a few moments ago, I kept on my CSS animations experiments with SVG, but now, regarding colourizing.

My initial idea was to apply the animation rules directly over the `<g>` tag grouping all `<path>`, hoping it would work "automagically". Yeah, right...

After convincing myself that I would really need to define the rules directly over the `<path>` inside, I thought I'd have to play around with timings, so the first shape would start with a colour and fades to the start colour of the second. Then the second shape would end with the colour of the first shape, simulating a back-and-forth effect.

Here:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box {
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #0f68e0;
}

.left {
  transform-origin: 190px 555px;
  animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

  .left path {
    animation: colorize-left 6s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }

.right {
  transform-origin: 605px 555px;
  animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

  .right path {
    animation: colorize-right 8s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes colorize-left {
  0% {
    fill: #0f68e0;
  }

  100% {
    fill: #1998ea;
  }
}

@keyframes colorize-right {
  0% {
    fill: #1998ea;
  }

  100% {
    fill: #0f68e0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<wrapper class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

  <main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="logo">

          <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-20 0 841.209 765.469" enable-background="new -20 0 840.209 765.469" xml:space="preserve">

            <g id="shapes">

              <circle id="left" cx="190" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="left">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,485.11c1.139-5.168,2.036-10.402,3.458-15.492
                                                                 c6.393-22.867,20.793-39.549,40.947-51.354c34.3-20.092,68.711-39.997,103.208-59.748c31.154-17.838,62.052-16.47,92.784,1.582
                                                                 c32.845,19.292,65.925,38.18,98.85,57.336c30.349,17.658,45.821,44.029,45.862,79.242c0.045,39.324,0.059,78.648-0.007,117.973
                                                                 c-0.058,34.592-15.114,60.828-44.834,78.314c-34.405,20.244-68.957,40.246-103.655,59.984c-28.94,16.463-58.437,16.797-87.462,0.377
                                                                 c-35.178-19.898-70.117-40.229-104.953-60.723c-24.501-14.416-39.667-35.475-43.343-64.141c-0.102-0.797-0.561-1.547-0.854-2.318
                                                                 C0,579.131,0,532.122,0,485.11z M70.932,555.338c0,22.164,0.074,44.326-0.081,66.488c-0.023,3.285,1.021,4.994,3.865,6.617
                                                                 c38.42,21.941,76.777,43.994,115.087,66.127c2.745,1.584,4.771,1.902,7.687,0.215c38.438-22.244,76.941-44.373,115.497-66.414
                                                                 c2.797-1.598,3.944-3.25,3.935-6.578c-0.124-44.158-0.115-88.316-0.016-132.475c0.007-3.215-0.884-5.018-3.791-6.678
                                                                 c-38.713-22.1-77.351-44.33-115.946-66.633c-2.487-1.436-4.269-1.418-6.729,0.002c-38.602,22.289-77.237,44.523-115.957,66.609
                                                                 c-2.979,1.699-3.626,3.627-3.611,6.732C70.982,511.346,70.931,533.342,70.932,555.338z"/>

              </g>

              <circle id="right" cx="605" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="right">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M796.181,555.313c0,19.5-0.115,39.002,0.025,58.502
                                                                 c0.257,35.969-15.705,62.445-46.587,80.311c-32.976,19.076-66.024,38.029-98.902,57.271c-31.076,18.188-62.064,18.539-93.234,0.455
                                                                 c-34.249-19.869-68.659-39.469-102.706-59.682c-28.814-17.105-43.453-42.863-43.624-76.43c-0.204-40-0.16-80.002-0.018-120
                                                                 c0.12-33.539,14.444-59.504,43.257-76.639c35.46-21.092,71.12-41.875,107.151-61.972c30.308-16.905,60.521-14.384,90.129,3.015
                                                                 c32.843,19.302,65.971,38.121,98.863,57.341c30.086,17.58,45.712,43.691,45.651,78.824
                                                                 C796.153,515.977,796.181,535.645,796.181,555.313z M728.073,555.583c0-21.832-0.099-43.664,0.093-65.496
                                                                 c0.034-3.813-1.063-5.908-4.44-7.838c-38.433-21.934-76.784-44.014-115.077-66.191c-2.938-1.701-5.012-1.23-7.662,0.297
                                                                 c-38.331,22.109-76.691,44.166-115.103,66.137c-2.759,1.58-3.927,3.246-3.917,6.592c0.133,44.33,0.119,88.662,0.021,132.992
                                                                 c-0.006,3.07,0.991,4.709,3.654,6.23c38.277,21.873,76.521,43.805,114.649,65.934c3.568,2.072,6.048,1.928,9.46-0.047
                                                                 c38.011-22.002,76.078-43.906,114.229-65.664c3.254-1.855,4.196-3.883,4.171-7.447C727.994,599.249,728.073,577.417,728.073,555.583
                                                                 z"/>

              </g>

            </g>

          </svg>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </main>

</wrapper>
```

But I obviously failed as the transitions aren't smooth as intended. Could anyone help me out here?

> Note: If needed, a small explanation would be nice because this SVG is just a fragment of the real thing, meaning more shapes will participate this timed transition

Answer (score 0):

You are almost good, the issue is that the last state of the animation is different from the first and since you made the animation to be `infinite` you will have a jump.

An idea to avoid this is to make the animation `alternate`. You need to also make both animation with the same duration and add a delay to only one element.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box {
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #0f68e0;
}

.left {
  transform-origin: 190px 555px;
  animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

  .left path {
    animation: colorize-left 4s linear infinite alternate;
  }

.right {
  transform-origin: 605px 555px;
  animation: spin-reverse 4000ms linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

  .right path {
    animation: colorize-right 4s linear infinite alternate;
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes colorize-left {
  0% {
    fill: #0f68e0;
  }

  100% {
    fill: #1998ea;
  }
}

@keyframes colorize-right {
  0% {
    fill: #1998ea;
  }

  100% {
    fill: #0f68e0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<wrapper class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

  <main class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="logo">

          <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-20 0 841.209 765.469" enable-background="new -20 0 840.209 765.469" xml:space="preserve">

            <g id="shapes">

              <circle id="left" cx="190" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="left">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,485.11c1.139-5.168,2.036-10.402,3.458-15.492
                                                                 c6.393-22.867,20.793-39.549,40.947-51.354c34.3-20.092,68.711-39.997,103.208-59.748c31.154-17.838,62.052-16.47,92.784,1.582
                                                                 c32.845,19.292,65.925,38.18,98.85,57.336c30.349,17.658,45.821,44.029,45.862,79.242c0.045,39.324,0.059,78.648-0.007,117.973
                                                                 c-0.058,34.592-15.114,60.828-44.834,78.314c-34.405,20.244-68.957,40.246-103.655,59.984c-28.94,16.463-58.437,16.797-87.462,0.377
                                                                 c-35.178-19.898-70.117-40.229-104.953-60.723c-24.501-14.416-39.667-35.475-43.343-64.141c-0.102-0.797-0.561-1.547-0.854-2.318
                                                                 C0,579.131,0,532.122,0,485.11z M70.932,555.338c0,22.164,0.074,44.326-0.081,66.488c-0.023,3.285,1.021,4.994,3.865,6.617
                                                                 c38.42,21.941,76.777,43.994,115.087,66.127c2.745,1.584,4.771,1.902,7.687,0.215c38.438-22.244,76.941-44.373,115.497-66.414
                                                                 c2.797-1.598,3.944-3.25,3.935-6.578c-0.124-44.158-0.115-88.316-0.016-132.475c0.007-3.215-0.884-5.018-3.791-6.678
                                                                 c-38.713-22.1-77.351-44.33-115.946-66.633c-2.487-1.436-4.269-1.418-6.729,0.002c-38.602,22.289-77.237,44.523-115.957,66.609
                                                                 c-2.979,1.699-3.626,3.627-3.611,6.732C70.982,511.346,70.931,533.342,70.932,555.338z"/>

              </g>

              <circle id="right" cx="605" cy="555" r="225" fill="transparent" />

              <g class="right">

                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M796.181,555.313c0,19.5-0.115,39.002,0.025,58.502
                                                                 c0.257,35.969-15.705,62.445-46.587,80.311c-32.976,19.076-66.024,38.029-98.902,57.271c-31.076,18.188-62.064,18.539-93.234,0.455
                                                                 c-34.249-19.869-68.659-39.469-102.706-59.682c-28.814-17.105-43.453-42.863-43.624-76.43c-0.204-40-0.16-80.002-0.018-120
                                                                 c0.12-33.539,14.444-59.504,43.257-76.639c35.46-21.092,71.12-41.875,107.151-61.972c30.308-16.905,60.521-14.384,90.129,3.015
                                                                 c32.843,19.302,65.971,38.121,98.863,57.341c30.086,17.58,45.712,43.691,45.651,78.824
                                                                 C796.153,515.977,796.181,535.645,796.181,555.313z M728.073,555.583c0-21.832-0.099-43.664,0.093-65.496
                                                                 c0.034-3.813-1.063-5.908-4.44-7.838c-38.433-21.934-76.784-44.014-115.077-66.191c-2.938-1.701-5.012-1.23-7.662,0.297
                                                                 c-38.331,22.109-76.691,44.166-115.103,66.137c-2.759,1.58-3.927,3.246-3.917,6.592c0.133,44.33,0.119,88.662,0.021,132.992
                                                                 c-0.006,3.07,0.991,4.709,3.654,6.23c38.277,21.873,76.521,43.805,114.649,65.934c3.568,2.072,6.048,1.928,9.46-0.047
                                                                 c38.011-22.002,76.078-43.906,114.229-65.664c3.254-1.855,4.196-3.883,4.171-7.447C727.994,599.249,728.073,577.417,728.073,555.583
                                                                 z"/>

              </g>

            </g>

          </svg>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </main>

</wrapper>
```

Comment: Hmmm... It's better, but there's still a noticeable jump when the animation is starting and, unless I'm having an optical illusion, I don't think I managed to reproduce the logic with more shapes. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKyamz), this was the closest I've got. I changed to more noticeable colours and I had to add a delay to the third shape I added or its animation would trigger right away. But still not right

Comment: Which browser are you using? There is no noticeable jump for me on Chrome or FF.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto well, with 3 shape it's more difficult than only 2 ... as you can see with 2 shapes I made the duration 4s and the dely of the second one 2s, so when the first one is on the first half the second one is on the second half ... with 3 shapes you need more complex logic in order to have similar effect ... let find you some SO questions dealing with this

Comment: I'd appreciate that, because I played around with smaller timings (i.e. milliseconds) for quite some time trying to get a full, uniform cycle lasting more or less 33% of the whole time each but when I've got that close I watched the animation and after while the first iterations went right but a few cycles later everything blew to mess, with two elements with the same colour visible at same time.